# Getting .set to work with an object array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to make a program where you put in a radius and it spits out the area, diameter etc. but whenever I run the app it crashes. Here's what I've got if anyone can help that would be much appreciated

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    MeasureC[] mc = new MeasureC[5];
    int i=0;
    int p =5;
    for(i=0;i<=p;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("What do you want the radius to be?");
        double UserRad = scan.nextDouble();

        mc[i].setRadius(UserRad);
        mc[i].setArea();
        mc[i].setDiameter();
        mc[i].setCircumfrence();
        System.out.println(mc[i].getRadius());
        System.out.println(mc[i].getArea());
        System.out.println(mc[i].getDiameter());
        System.out.println(mc[i].getCircumfrence());

    }
```

Here's the second class:

```
public class MeasureC {
    private double radius, area, diameter, circumfrence;

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double newRadius) {
        radius = newRadius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea() {
        area = 3.14*radius;
    }

    public double getDiameter() {
        return diameter;
    }

    public void setDiameter() {
        diameter = 2*radius;
    }

    public double getCircumfrence() {
        return circumfrence;
    }

    public void setCircumfrence() {
        circumfrence = 3.14*(2*radius);
}
```

Comment: What is the intended behavior here?  Would you _only_ be inputting the radius, and expect to get out all other components?  Or, would it be possible to just enter the area and also get all other components?

Comment: The radius is the only input allowed. It would not be possible to enter the area

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note for future questions that "it crashes" is not nearly as useful as "it crashes with the following exception" - including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MeasureC[] mc = new MeasureC[5];
```

This doesn't create an array of 5 `MeasureC` objects, it just allocates the space for them in memory. So, currently, every index points to `null`. That means that in your `for` loop when you try and access a particular element in your array you will get an error as `.setRadius()` etc... is not a method of `null`:

```
mc[i].setRadius(UserRad); // mc[i] is null
```

So, to fix this issue, you can create a new instance of your `MeasureC` class at each iteration and set it at your index:

```
for(i = 0; i < p; i++) { // set to i < p as max index in your array is 4 (not 5)
  mc[i] = new MeasureC();
  // code...
}
```

Comment: Note that there are many other problems with the OP's code, beyond what is contained here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

`for(i=0;i<=p;i++)`

by:

`for(i=0;i<p;i++)`

as now you iterate 6 times on 5 dimension array and got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get a `NullPointerException` at the line `mc[i].setRadius(UserRad);`.

Think about what that means. Then it should be obvious what line you have to add before that to fix the problem.

Hint: Think about how Java does array initializations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the radius to be the only input data allowed, we can try refactoring your code as (see notes below):

```
public class MeasureC {
    private double radius, area, diameter, circumference;

    public MeasureC (double radius) {
        diameter = 2.0d * radius;
        circumference = Math.pi * diameter;
        area = Math.pi * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    }

    public double getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }
    public double getArea(){
        return area;
    }
    public double getDiameter(){
        return diameter;
    }
    public double getCircumfrence(){
        return circumfrence;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int p = 5;
    MeasureC[] mc = new MeasureC[p];
    for (int i=0; i <= p; i++) {
        System.out.println("What do you want the radius to be?");
        double userRad = scan.nextDouble();
        mc[i] = new Measure(userRad);
        System.out.println(mc[i].getRadius());
        System.out.println(mc[i].getArea());
        System.out.println(mc[i].getDiameter());
        System.out.println(mc[i].getCircumfrence());
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I expose a single constructor in your `MeasureC` class which accepts an input radius as a double.  Inside that constructor I compute, using that input radius, the diameter, circumference, and area.
- Since you only want the circle to be configurable via the radius, I removed setters for the diameter, circumference, and area.
- A problem you had in your `main()` method was that you were not instantiating your `MeasureC` instances with `new`.  I am doing this now.
- Java naming conventions say that variable names should begin with lowercase letters, while class names begin with uppercase.  Both are camelcase for subsequent letters.  You should stick with this convention.